# How to make height squeeze with css

Tags: html, css

I've got [an example mht file here](https://gist.github.com/raw/873557/c4ce94457d3ee276f9a9d5f2f6d7dcedb089aa26/aexample.mht) that will help demonstrate my issue; if you are using FF then [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozilla-archive-format/) will help you view the mht file. You will prob need to download the file and view it locally since github doesn't provide the right mime type for the file.

Basically my issue is this that I have a `div` which is 32px in height surrounding another `div` which is 29px in height, and I have no idea why the former is 32px tall.. It should be 29px tall afaict.. I don't want to set `height:29px` tho because if you resize the window so that the nav items take two lines then the height shouldn't be 29px for either `div`.

**So what is wrong here?**

Comment: For future reference, I think I should point this out: I read your question the same day it was posted, but the weird MHT file put me off; with a more accessible test case, I'd have answered rapidly.

Comment: @Eric Vold, yes, for the record, I would never have bothered with answering this question if @clairesuzy's link wasn't available.

Comment: I'll use jsbin next time, sorry.

Comment: Erik, Thank You; as for the the code convert, I'm quite new to SO, but you offered a bounty suggesting you wanted to take the time to get some work put into the right solution for you, and you were very fair taking time to inform via your comments, explaining the "buts" for your use case - AND at least you gave a link to the mht reader, which was new to me and is useful! - so I think that balances the time spent recoding.. just my opinion of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the use of `display: inline-block;` on the `ul.base` is the cause.

when you use that it formats an element like it were inline (it only formats the actual content of the element like a block), so `ul.base` will have the usual 2-3px top and bottom "padding" that a normal inline element has. It's not really padding it's the <strike>leading</strike> vertical spacing  i.e. it's what gives lines enough space to provide for the ascenders and descenders of letters like g, h, p, etc.

the use of it here is to make it seem like your ul is containing the floated child list elements. To make an element contain it's floated children there are other ways to do this, one way is, on `ul.base`

remove: `display: inline-block` 
add: `overflow: hidden;`

**[UPDATED]** re the tabs.. sorry I didn't see them before I started

Here's the "float everything" solution to containing child floats as it applies to your code, with some other suggestions too

1. `.menuContainer` all it needs is position:relative; and the border-right rule
2. `.navigationSecondary` float it left with a width of 100%; (you can remove z-index it's not doing anything)
3. `.wrapper` float it left with a width of 100%, remove the height
4. `ul.base` doesn't actually need anything but remove the display-inline-block.. it's not containing the child lists but there's no effect involved, if you want to you can float it left with a 100% width too

**[UPDATE 2]**
I just copied this to a plain HTML document and *I think* that just changing the DOCTYPE to an HTML4 transitional one solves the problems with no changes to the code ?? (why that should change the display be I don't quite know! - but the use of "target=_parent" is "not allowed" in Strict Doctypes so that'll be why it's not validating)

I'll put it in JSBIN so others can try it out on various browsers

I changed it to:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

jsbin (with **original** HTML5 doctype) is here [http://jsbin.comhttp://jsbin.com/agihe5/2/](http://jsbin.com/agihe5/2/) - shows gap

jsbin **with changed Doctype**  - but no changes to CSS code - with flash video to show dropdowns are working is here : http://jsbin.com/inare6/2 - no gap!

jsbin with no changes to Doctype, suggested changes to code and the flash insert to show z-index working is here: http://jsbin.com/iriya4

with the latter, code changes are detailed in the source, they have moved to the bottom of the snapshot CSS

I've tested the changed Doctype version as working in IE7, IE8, FF3.6.15, Safari4 (Win) and Chrome

Comment: these tabs actually have drop down menus which are out of sight with the overflow:hidden prop; otherwise tho this worked perfectly.

Comment: sorry Erik, never saw the tabs, have now updated with the other "float everything" solution - floated container also contain their children, but as you have 3 containers creating the effect you have to float them all.. hth

Comment: just fyi the z-index stuff is because of a Flash element that is displayed under this navigation html.

Comment: That's cool thanks, but in that case you'll need to set navigationSecondary to position: relative as well then, z-index only works if the element is positioned relatively or absolutely, that's what I meant by "not doing anything" - didn't mean to suggest you wouldn't need it. Either that or relatively position and z-index the menuContainer instead - you should only need the to lift the whole menu stack on one root/parent div, thx.

Comment: The gap is the descender of the text, not the ascender nor the leading (leading is a different thing akin to line spacing).  Default for an inline-block is to position on the baseline, leaving the descender as the "gap" on the bottom.  Solution is to use `vertical-align:bottom` to position it on the bottom of the element instead of on the baseline.

Comment: I think I wrote that in my answer? - "ascenders and descenders of letters like g, h, p, etc". but point taken about the wrong use of the word leading .. you are correct that, that is one solution but to me containing the floats is the more correct one.. CSS has so many solutions doesn't it ;)

Comment: and @Stephen it was me who downloaded and rewrote the code, but thanks for saying it was commendable.. I'll take the compliment :)

Comment: Yes, @clairesuzy, your one-click link was great!  :-)  I would never have bothered with this question if your link wasn't available!

Comment: You're Welcome Erik, glad it helped - a bounty should require a bit of extra effort - thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 3):

make the following changes-

(-) to make your `ul` and `wrapper div` bottoms to align change class `#navigationSecondary ul.base`
to have a `display:table;` instead of `display:inline-block;`

(-) to remove the 3px of blue at the bottom change class `#navigationSecondary` to have `padding:0;` as sugested by Marcel.

Comment: can you setup a test page somewhere so tat its easier to try out diff browsers

Comment: have you tried setting line-height: and font-size: manually yet?

Comment: There is an eaiser way to handle `inline-block` than to replace it with a table display, which is to override the vertical position such that it does not position on the baseline (the default).

Answer (score 2):

Providing a test case which requires me to use Firefox and download an extension to view it is *highly annoying*.

I just did it anyway (purely because of the bounty), and the only change you need to make to your test case is:

- On `#navigationSecondary ul.base`, add `vertical-align: top`.
- The extra height is gone.

Here's a demo based on @clairesuzy's demo titled `"jsbin (with original HTML5 doctype)"`. 
*(The only change was adding the aforementioned CSS rule)*:

http://jsbin.com/agihe5/3

The other answers may work (I didn't test them), but (providing I've understood the issue properly), this is by far the easiest fix.

Comment: @thirtydot, vertical-align:bottom works also, but top also does the job, since it takes away the default which is to position on the baseline, leaving a descender gap at the bottom.  Your huge efforts in downloading the document and viewing it in FF is commendable... :-)  I would never have bothered if somebody else didn't do it for me to just click at a link...

Comment: @Stephen Chung: Your answer explains the problem well. I didn't bother to write up a description of *why* my fix worked, all my effort was wasted on getting the test case going :p

Comment: @thirtydot, when I first saw the question I wasn't going to bother with it (like spliting a multi-part MIME article and stuff).  Then I saw one of the answers posted a link and just clicked on it.  Saw the problem right there within around 30 seconds.  Didn't really get to your answer when I wrote it up; otherwise I probably would have just posted some comment on yours.

Comment: I work a lot with Asian languages (which is frustrating when aligned on the baseline) and so `inline-block` automatically rings an alarm bell.  I am surprised, though, that people didn't pick up on this immediately -- it seemed obvious.

Comment: @Stephen Chung: Yup, I had the same experience; instantly knowing how to fix it after seeing `inline-block`. I'm glad you didn't see my answer, your answer is a nice explanation.

Comment: @thirtydot, I think by being first with identifying the problem, my opinion is that you should get the bounty.  However, I think that for a bounty, the OP deserves a more detailed writeup.  That's why I wrote it long.

Comment: @thirtydot, I have upvoted you.  Not sure why nobody upvoted your answer before -- yours is the first one with a clear indication of the right solution and the correct identity of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `#navigationSecondary` has `padding:0 0 3px;` set in `unnamed-1.css` on `line 2`.

Comment: that 3px padding is what lets the blue at the bottom show, which is what a selected tab should be connected with

Comment: ie: there should be 3px of blue at the botton, a selected tab is the same color of blue, and there should be no orange below a selected tab (or any tab for that matter)

Comment: Well that's where the extra height comes from.

Comment: no it's not, if I remove `padding:0 0 3px;` from `#navigationSecondary` with firebug there is still 3px of orange under the selected tab (and others)..

Answer (score 1):

Everything inside **ul.base** has a height of 24px. Itself has a padding of 2px. So it's height is 26px. It's parent **div.wrapper** has a height of 29px, 3px extra. It's not caused by the 3px padding of **div#navigationSecondary**. Nothing is contributing the extra 3px so I'm suspecting a float issue. Anyway I managed to fix it by floating 2 divs.

- Add `float: left; width: 100%;` to **div.wrapper** and **div#navigationSecondary**.
- Remove `display: inline-block;` from **ul.base**.

Floating `div.wrapper` and `div#navigationSecondary` collapses them to their nearest floated child element, in this case `li.base`, and removes the extra 3px. 100% width brings back the stretch.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's a float issue. This solution fixes your problem.

Comment: it is not a float issue.  The `inline-block` is what is causing the 3px.  It positions the element on the baseline of the text font.  The font has a 3px descender at that particular size.

Comment: @Stephen Chung the second step I suggested is to remove inline-block. My solution did exactly what the chosen answer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body style="zoom:0.99; -moz-transform: scale(0.99); -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;">
```

adjust accordingly, and change hight and width around

Answer (score 1):

Of course.  This is simple.  A very elementary element positioning issue.

### inline-block default vertical-positioning

`ul.base` is an **inline-block**.  which means that it has spacing calculated like a block, but *positioned like an inline-element*.

The default positioning of inline-element is to align on the baseline of text.  However, text goes **below** the baseline for letters such as g, j, q etc.  This is called "descenders".

The height of a box is always from the top of the font to the bottom of the descenders.

The wrapper takes on the height of its children.  Which means that the inline-block ul.base, **positioned on the baseline**.

Your font at that particular size happens to have a 3-pixel descender.  Voila.  Your mysterious 3-pixel gap is merely the text's descenders.  And your `inline-block` element is positioned on the baseline (i.e. on top of that 3 pixels).

### Tests to confirm that this is right

1. Change font size.  You'll see that 3-pixel changes.  Change font size to small enough and it'll reduce to a 1px descender.  Your so-called "gap" will shrink.
2. Change `ul.base` to something other than an `inline-block` (of course you have to add something to clear the floats inside).  It will no longer have the 3 pixels at the bottom because a non-inline element is not positioned on the baseline.
3. Position `ul.base` on the absolute bottom instead of the default (baseline).  That 3-pixel gap disappears.  Use this CSS rule: `vertical-align:bottom`

### Morale of the story

You always have to be careful with baseline positioning whenever you use `inline-block` display style.

### Off topic

Handling font descenders is especially frustrating with Asian languages.  As you know, CJK languages do not have characters that go below the baseline.  However, they are typically placed on the baseline (so that they can inter-mix with other European languages, which have descenders).  However, when one places a block of text with a background containing *only Asian characters*, the text will look like it is moved to the top, with an ugly empty gap on the bottom (the descender).